# Oracle 12c impdp fails when executed fromt the command line

Tags: oracle, database-administration, impdp

Trying to use impdp to do a data refresh on an Oracle 12c database:

Receive the following error after invoking the impdp from the command line:

```
ORA-39006: internal error
ORA-39065: unexpected master process exception in DISPATCH
ORA-00942: table or view does exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPU$UTILITIES_INT", line 1579
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPM$MCP", line 2710
ORA-39097: Data Pump encountered unexpected error -942
```

I found a post that made reference to GSM objects not being available, but there was no confirmation or response to this.

All the GSM schemas have been removed from the database I am working in.

Comment: Have a look at Oracle support document 2341607.1

Comment: Thanks --- this seemed to solve the problem. It may have created others one, but at least I'm unstuck from where I was. Again. many thanks.

Comment: so what how do you solve this?

Comment: rebuilding broken packages and running scripts (from %ORA_HOME%\rdbms\admin\ dir) did not help me:
catalog.sql
catproc.sql
utlrp.sql